# Android SDK manager does not download all API levels

Tags: android

I have observed problems with more recent versions of the SDK(-tools) where an `android update sdk --no-ui` does not pull down all platform versions anymore. We just set up a new headless build server and went with a fresh installation of the SDK, but that command refuses to pull down API level 9 (Gingerbread):

```
ateam@gandalf:~/android/sdk/platforms$ ls
android-10  android-11  android-12  android-13  android-14  android-3  android-4  android-7  android-8
```

It is missing API levels 5 and 6, since they are deprecated, so that's fine, but Gingerbread should be there?

```
ateam@gandalf:~/android/sdk/platforms$ android update sdk --no-ui
...
There is nothing to install or update.
```

Anyone else having this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

API levels 9 and 10 are both gingerbread (see [API levels](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html)). 10 is the newer version, 9 is  obsolete. And obsolete packages are not selected for downloading by default.

Comment: Ah! Completely missed that. Thanks!

Comment: However, android-9 is not even listed now. Why? Edit: Got it, I have to check "Obsolete".